# passing two JSON model objects from PHP to JS via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

im using Laravel for a fairly simple app.

i have this in a controller function working great:

```
    if(Request::ajax())
    {
        $joke = Joke::where('type', '=', 'kid')->get()->random(1);

        if (Session::has('joke'))
        {
            Session::forget('joke');
        }

        Session::put('joke', $joke);
        return Response::json($joke);
    }
```

however, if I change the last lines to:

```
Session::put('joke', $joke);
$user = $joke->user;
return Response::json([ 'joke' => $joke, 'user' => $user);
```

the ajax call succeeds but i cant use $joke or $user in my JS anymore.

here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { rating: userRating },
        success: function(data){
            var textString = 'Thanks for rating! This little gems score is a sweet ' + data.joke.rating + '!';
            $('.jokeRating').html(textString);

        },
        error: function(){
            // load a message indicating it didnt work
            $('.jokeRating').html('It didnt work, sorry!');
        },
    });
```

what i would like to add is something like

```
var authorString = '~' + data.user.name;
            $('.author').html(author);
```

the eloquent relationship is set up correctly. $joke->user definitely works, as I placed:

```
Route::get('/var', function()
{
$joke = Joke::find(1);
$user = $joke->user;
dd($user);
});
```

in routes.php and it comes through perfectly.

where am i tripping up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the User and Joke objects to arrays before returning them:

```
if(Request::ajax())
{
    $joke = Joke::where('type', '=', 'kid')->get()->random(1);

    if (Session::has('joke'))
    {
        Session::forget('joke');
    }

    Session::put('joke', $joke);
    return Response::json([ 'joke' => $joke->toArray(), 'user' => $user->toArray()]);
}
```

Comment: thank you, this also works like the toJson method. however, it won't let me access my variables in js like i want to. data.joke.joke or data.user.email break the script. if i display just 'data.joke' it comes through with both JSON objects and all their properties, if i display 'data.user' its just the user JSON object. how do i properly access this on success in AJAX?

Comment: edit: Nevermind, it actually works with yours but not with toJson. thank you very much!